# Embedded Youtube video doesn't work on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, youtube, youtube-api

Here's [My Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/YpPR7/3/)

I currently have an animation,where **at the end of it**,i have a video.

It works **fine on chrome,but not on firefox.**
My version is 26.0 ,Mozilla firefox.

This is the part where i **show the video iframe.**

```
function showIframe() {
    $("#container").addClass("hideContainer");
    $("#livingRoomBG").append("<iframe id='video' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/BIz02qY5BRA?autoplay=1'  frameborder='1' allowfullscreen=''></iframe>");
    $("#livingRoomBG").addClass("showlivingRoomBG");
    console.log("ola")
}
```

Can someone explain why this is happening?

PS:The audio does come though,cuz i have put it on autoplay..

Answer (score 0):

the most likely cause to this is some kind of Firefox addon, have you tried opening it in safe mode?

Comment: ok it could be a security permission, firefox added security around https sites, remove the s from the url and try again eg: http:// www. youtube

Comment: it actually works on my frnds pc,but not mine.
Same version though.
Any idea why?

Comment: again only thing i can think of is some kind of addon or blocker/setting on your browser